# Array Binding in NSViewRepresentable Updating Incorrectly After Sorting

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, nsviewrepresentable

I have a `ForEach` binding to an array of items. Each item has an index (which represents how it should be sorted), and some text. Each row in the `ForEach` has an `NSTextView` in an `NSViewRepresentable` (I can't use `TextEditor` for various reasons), which uses the binding for the item's `text`. However, after sorting the list, if I update the NSTextView, one of the other views gets the update as well:

[image: Updating NSTextView after sorting items in list causes another to update]

Here's my code:

```swift
struct ListItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    
    var index: Int
    var text: String
    var id = UUID()
    
    static let initialItems: [ListItem] = [
        .init(index: 2, text: "String 2"),
        .init(index: 0, text: "String 0"),
        .init(index: 1, text: "String 1"),
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items = ListItem.initialItems
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach($items) { item in
                HStack {
                    TextField("Index: ", value: item.index, format: .number)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    TVRep(text: item.text)
                }
            }
            Button("Sort!")  {
                items.sort(by: {$0.index < $1.index})
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}

struct TVRep: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
        let view = NSTextView()
        view.string = text
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
        nsView.string = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TVRep!
        
        init(parent: TVRep) {
            super.init()
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let tv = notification.object as? NSTextView else {return}
            parent.text = tv.string
        }
        
    }
}
```

This doesn't occur when using SwiftUI's built-in `TextEditor`. Interestingly, this only seems to happen when I update the `text` binding's value within the Representable view - if I don't have the delegate method updating the binding value, this doesn't occur.

I do know that if I call `sorted(by:)` in the `ForEach` argument that it will update properly, but that means that the moment that the `TextField` for the index is updated, the views are sorted, while I want to be able to sort them manually.

Comment: In `ContentView`, try using `$item` in the `ForEach`, the `TextField` and the `TVRep` call.

Comment: When binding to an array in SwiftUI, the argument for the closure is the binding. i.e. there's no "$item" since "item" is already `Binding<ListItem>`